# Pycharm using wrong python.X library for packages

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pycharm

I am using PyCharm 2016.3 on Windows 10 to work with python. I currently have 2 different projects, one with Anaconda python3.5, my 1st project. Works perfectly so far. I had to import external modules, using the terminal (pip install).

I have a new project whith which I must use Anaconda python2.7. Thus I install it and add it to pycharm.Seems to work fine with the Python console.

```
C:\Anaconda2\python.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py" 53481 53482
Python 2.7.12 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jun 29 2016, 11:07:13) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
Python 2.7.12 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jun 29 2016, 11:07:13) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

Here again, I have to install external modules, using the terminal with

```
pip install cchardet
```

I got this message from the terminal:

```
Requirement already satisfied: cchardet in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
```

Thus, it seems that there is some variable still in Python3.5 whereas, in settings/Project interpreter, it uses Python 2.7.12, as requested.

Before asking my question, I find some clue on the variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH, which I pointed to "C:/Anaconda2/Lib/" in Build,Execution,Deployment/Console/Python Console and in Run/Edit Configurations/Default/Python/Environment variables. But doesn't solve the issue.

I am not an expert in Python, especially concerning those meta variables (path and so on). So my question is: does anyone knows how to point Pycharm to the proper lib, in respect with the version I use, depending on the project?

Thanks a lot

Mattias

Comment: This may be a perfect place to use virtual environments.

Answer (score 1):

To point to correct python environment while using terminal, `anaconda\bin` should be exported in global path.

In terminal before running `pip install`, run following:

`set PATH=anaconda2.7\bin;%PATH`

This will install dependency in anaconda 2.7

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I run your command, and then when I run the $pip install$ it answers: $'pip' n’est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.$ which means more or less than $pip$ is not anymore regonize as a command. When I restart Pycharm, it works again but go back to the Python3 lib...